# How to sort lines based on variable:value using linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have few lines like below were I need to sort and print the lines based on variable:value

```
15:16:31.640 [Executor task launch worker for task 85] INFO  IAME- Sum id:705 SignatureId : EDXGH  Events:1320 Time Taken By All Events:11 eps:12000.0 Process Time on Average (in ms) for each event:0.008333333333333333
15:16:31.640 [Executor task launch worker for task 85] INFO  IAME- Sum id:231 SignatureId : EDXGH  Events:60 Time Taken By All Events:13 eps:6000.0 Process Time on Average (in ms) for each event:0.016666666666666666
15:16:31.640 [Executor task launch worker for task 85] INFO  IAME- Sum id:644 SignatureId : EDXGH  Events:1320 Time Taken By All Events:909 eps:14666.666666666666 Process Time on Average (in ms) for each event:0.006818181818181818
```

I am trying to sort the lines based on "Time Taken By All Events:909"
I am expecting to see the output as below

```
15:16:31.640 [Executor task launch worker for task 85] INFO  IAME- Sum id:644 SignatureId : EDXGH  Events:1320 Time Taken By All Events:909 eps:14666.666666666666 Process Time on Average (in ms) for each event:0.006818181818181818
15:16:31.640 [Executor task launch worker for task 85] INFO  IAME- Sumid:768 SignatureId : EDXGH Events:1320 Time Taken By All Events:13 eps:10153.846153846152 Process Time on Average (in ms) for each event:0.009848484848484848
15:16:31.640 [Executor task launch worker for task 85] INFO  IAME- Sum id:705 SignatureId : EDXGH  Events:1320 Time Taken By All Events:11 eps:12000.0 Process Time on Average (in ms) for each event:0.008333333333333333
```

Any help on how to get this using linux commands

Comment: Your input and output do not match.

Answer (score 2):

This is the ["decorate-sort-undecorate"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) pattern: it extracts the number you want to sort by, puts it at the front of the line, sorts, then removes the number

```sh
paste <(grep -oP 'Time Taken By All Events:\K\d+' file) file \
| sort -nr -k1,1 \
| cut -f2-
```

I assume *every* line contains the "time taken by all events" -- the paste output will be wrong if that assumption is false.

---

Same concept, different command to, now, **filter** and decorate:

```sh
perl -lne 'print "$1\t$_ file" if /Time Taken By All Events:(\d+)/' file \
| sort -nr -k1,1 \
| cut -f2-
```

Comment: it contains some other unwanted lines as well

Comment: And how are those supposed to be sorted? Add **all details** into your question

Comment: I have other lines as well , but I need those lines which have the key word "Time Taken by" and those lines need to be sorted based on the value as updated

Answer (score 0):

Another form of decorate-sort-undecorate:

```
sed -E 's/^(.*Time Taken By All Events:)([0-9]*)(.*)$/\2 \1\2\3/' file | sort -nr -k1,1 | sed -E 's/^([^[:space:]]* )(.*)/\2/'
```